# Custom VNC client for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ios4, vnc

I'm looking around to see if there's a library for building my own roll of VNC for iPhone/iPad ... from what i saw now; the only library that 'could' meet my needs is '[Chicken](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/)' (a fork of CoVNC)

Seems to be for MacOS but 'should' be running on iOS, right ?

(Sorry for my newbee'ness, starting here).